# GCP, Container Built with Google Cloud Built and Dockerfile isn't listening on port 8080

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a cloudbuild job that failed because the container isn't listening on port 8080. But, when I run the container locally, I have no problem accessing it on port 8080. Here are the error, cloudbuild.yaml, and Dockerfile. I need help figuring out where is the problem.

Errors:
Filter to find the logs:

```
resource.type = "cloud_run_revision"
resource.labels.service_name = "icognition-api-scv"
resource.labels.location = "us-central1"
 severity>=DEFAULT
```

To see the logs in JSON:
Cloud Run: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l_AV4lk0CYYLY49DQnSEtBOMqUPGzr-F/view?usp=sharing

Cloud Build: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T1o0f8kLjM4oOSxlfHJPiKr43WODYGcY/view?usp=sharing

cloudbuild:

```
steps:
- id: "Build Docker Image"
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker:latest'
  dir: '.'
  args: ['build', 
          '-t', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/icognition-api-artifact-registry/icognition-api-img',
          '.']

- id: "Push Docker Image To Artifact Registry"
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker:latest'
  args: ['push', '--all-tags', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/icognition-api-artifact-registry/icognition-api-img']

- id: "Deploy Cloud Run Service"
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud:latest'
  args: [
    'run', 'deploy', 'icognition-api-scv', 
    '--service-account' ,'sa-icognition-api-svc@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    '--allow-unauthenticated',
    '--memory', '512Mi',
    '--platform', 'managed',
    '--image', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/icognition-api-artifact-registry/icognition-api-img',
    '--port', '8080',
    '--timeout', '30',
    '--min-instances', '0',
    '--max-instances', '1',
    '--ingress', 'all',
    '--region', 'us-central1',
    '--set-secrets', 'DATABASE_URL=icog-db-stg-secret:latest',
    '--network' ,'default',
    '--subnet', 'default',
    '--vpc-egress', 'private-ranges-only'
    ]
timeout: 600s
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
  dynamic_substitutions: true
```

Dockerfile:

```
# 
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Install libraries
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the app to the container
COPY ./app ./app

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the app
CMD uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

Comment: How long take your container to start? Why do you use the alpha gcloud command and not the main stream? Do you have errors before your logs trace in Cloud Loggings? Did you test your container outside Cloud Run service? on your workstation for instance?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere, thank you. I added the log error I see in the Cloud Logs. The Cloud Run step fails after 50 seconds. Regarding why I am using 'alpha,' what was employed in the example I followed from the Udemy course.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am not sure where I should look for logs. Here is the query I used to get the logs
```resource.type = "cloud_run_revision"
resource.labels.service_name = "icognition-api-scv"
resource.labels.location = "us-central1"
 severity>=DEFAULT```. 
To see the JSON dump of them - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l_AV4lk0CYYLY49DQnSEtBOMqUPGzr-F/view?usp=sharing
The Udemy course is from 03/2023.

Comment: I added to the description the links to the Cloud Run and Cloud Build JSON logs. I also, remove the *alpha* and test it again and still the same error.

Comment: I need the alpha for the network argument. I got this message without it: 
--network flag is available in one or more alternate release tracks. Try:
gcloud alpha run deploy --network

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in your code, but you have a log entry with this payload `"textPayload": "Container called exit(0).",`, So if the container exit, the healthcheck obviously fail. If you pull your container and run it locally it could fail in the same way. You must debug it and understand why it exits immediately at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solves your problem:

```
FROM python:3.10

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question. There were two issues that confused me.

1. The logs were filtered to Cloud Build, and as a result, I didn't see the errors in the Cloud Run. Lesson: Remove the default filter. In the end the root cause was typo in environment variable name. This error was in the Cloud Run error, not the Cloud Build.
2. Rebuilding from the history tab, doesn't refetch the cloudbuild.yaml. As result, I had many builds that kept failing because the changes to Cloudbuild were not applied. I needed to trigger the build from the

Comment: Your post does not provide details on what the problem was, only the steps you followed to get the log information.

Comment: I fixed that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your application to listen on the `PORT` environment variable. While the `EXPOSE` command in the Dockerfile signals the ports that a container listens to, it doesn't by itself make those ports accessible externally. Instead, you'll have to ensure that the service hosting your container, such as Cloud Run, routes traffic correctly to the port specified by the `PORT` environment variable your application uses.

You may also review this documentation - [Configure the container port](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/containers#configure-port)